# Why is the terminal displaying gibberish?

Tags: terminal

On a usual day, I was using the PyCharm terminal.

I paused to see Youtube, and when I returend to PyCharm, my terminal was all messed up.

What can cause the characters on a terminal to be replaced by gibberish?

[image]

Comment: Could be because that font is not supported well.

Comment: But it works perfectly fine all the time, except this one incident!